# Sorting a table within a table

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I am several tables within a big table and I am using jquery tablesorter for sorting the main table.

I would like to be able to sort the individual tables within the main table as well. Example code:

```
 <table class="info tablesorter" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th colspan>The Name</th>
                    <th>Geography</th>
                    <th colspan="5">Prospective clients</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                        <Tr class="parent" id="id_1" style='background-color: white'>

                        <TD style=vertical-align:middle>Main echo 1</td>
                        <TD style=vertical-align:middle>New York, NY</td>
                        <td colspan="5">55</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="child-id_1 expand-child" style="display:none">
                        <td colspan='7'>
                        <table class="ctable_1 ts2" width=75% id="class_id_1">

                        <thead><tr>
                            <th>URL</th>
                            <th>Contact Page</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>GoogleIndex</th>
                            <th>Listed in next?</th>
                            <th>Created On</th>
                        </tr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class='childofmarket'>
                            <td> xyz </td>
                            <td> aaa</td>
                            <td> ###-###-#### </td>
                            <td>127</td>
                            <td>- No -</td>
                            <td>03-09-2011</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='childofmarket'>
                            <td> aak</td>
                            <td>csa</td>

                            <td>##########</td>
                            <td>69</td>
                            <td>- No -</td>
                            <td>03-09-2011</td>
                        </tr>
```

and so on. I keep getting the

> Error: parsers[i] is undefined

Can anyone tell me what I need to fix here?

Comment: can you give us a fiddler demo? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/K6CFk/show/0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you have tried but give all your tables the same class IE. sorted_table

please say which tablesorter you are using, I prefer this one [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

this in javascript use something like

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('.sorted_table').tablesorter();
});
```

Comment: Thats the plugin I am using and I have tried that, but since the tables are nested inside a table, the sorting fails